# What's wrong with this interface?

Tags: java

What (if anything) is wrong with the following interface?

```
public interface WorldsBestInterface {
    void favoriteMethod(int greatValue){
        System.out.println("Thanks for the smile");
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue figuring this out.

Comment: Just try compiling it, and you will find out!

Comment: This just show what you weren't paying much attention in class and you haven't even tried googling about [interfaces in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: Cool story bro @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't contain implementation. Interface contains just method declaration, it doesn't contain implementation.

```
void favoriteMethod(int greatValue){
        System.out.println("Thanks for the smile");
    }
```

It should be

```
 public interface WorldsBestInterface {
    void favoriteMethod(int greatValue);
}
```

Comment: Right!! Thank you. I know that's one of the rules for interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

Interfaces don't have any code in them, just signatures.

```
public interface WorldsBestInterface {
    void favoriteMethod(int greatValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, interfaces only define the structure of a class.  It's a contract to classes that implement it saying that if you choose to use it then you MUST also include the methods defined here. So any class that implements it is guaranteed to have what the interface has.

An alternative to this would be an abstract class if you need to have code within the methods.  You would then have to subclass it in order make it usable.

Answer (score 1):

In case of an interface, we only provide method signatures. However, if there exists a case where certain methods needs to have concrete implementation whereas others will only have method signature, consider using creating an abstract class. For example

```
public abstract class WorldsBestAbstractClass{
  public void favoriteMethod(int greatValue){
        System.out.println("Thanks for the smile");
    }

  public abstract void nextFavoriteMethod(int smallValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
public interface WorldsBestInterface {
   void favoriteMethod(int greatValue);  // no body, just declaration
}
```